# Generar un ciclo para sumar dias a una fecha

Tags: java

Buen día estoy tratando de que a una determinada fecha se le sumen días sin contar sábados y domingos cuando llega a viernes le incrementa el día pero el resultado es sábado posteriormente ya no hace nada por la condición del if():

```
while (dias<=num_dias_afectar) 
         {

            if (fechaInicialcalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && fechaInicialcalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) 
                {

                    fechaInicialcalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    Date fecha_fin = fechaInicialcalendar.getTime();
                    fecha_termino = format.format(fecha_fin);
                    dias++;

                }

        }
```

¿Como puedo evitar que el resultado sea sábado o en otro caso el resultado sea lunes?

Comment: Otro if. Si es viernes no sumar uno sino 3 dias por el precio de uno.

Comment: Saca el dias ++ fuera del if. En caso de q no cumpla con la condición no  simaria dias.

Comment: Excelente observación pero no saque el ++, saque  el fechaInicialcalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1) y ya brinca de viernes a lunes Gracias por el comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
 while (dias<=num_dias_afectar) 
         {

            if (fechaInicialcalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && fechaInicialcalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) 
                {       

                        Date fecha_fin = fechaInicialcalendar.getTime();
                        fecha_termino = format.format(fecha_fin);
                        dias++;    
                }
            fechaInicialcalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);       
        }
```

Comment: en vez de  && tiene que ser || por que ahí estás comparando dos días al mismo tiempo y solo basta con que una de las dos condiciones se cumpla